# Why does a Fragment need to be enclosed in a ViewGroup in newer versions of Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Google's tutorial app (which uses the support library by default)
http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/FragmentBasics.zip
contains a two-pane layout for `-large` screens.  After successfully compiling and running with min/target SDK at 4/15, I deleted all support library stuff and am trying to modernize to SDK 14/19 as an exercise.

Here is the two-pane layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment android:name="com.example.HeadlinesFragment"
              android:id="@+id/headlines_fragment"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <fragment android:name="com.example.ArticleFragment"
              android:id="@+id/article_fragment"
              android:layout_weight="2"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

When the `ArticleFragment` is instantiated, the XML that ships with the tutorial is **not** wrapped in a ViewGroup:

```
// ArticleFragment.java
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // If activity recreated (such as from screen rotate), restore
    // the previous article selection set by onSaveInstanceState().
    // This is primarily necessary when in the two-pane layout.
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mCurrentPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(ARG_POSITION);
    }

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_view, container, false);
}
```

and

```
// res/layout/article_view.xml
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/article"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:textSize="18sp" />
```

This arrangement returns null when something like this is run later:  `getActivity().findViewById(R.id.article);`

I discovered through trial and error and the hierarchy viewer, that the solution to this is to wrap the `article_view` in a `LinearLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/article"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Did something change between the support library and the modern Fragment implementations?

Updated to include MainActivity callback and ArticleFragment update code:

```
// MainActivity.java
public static class MainActivity extends Activity
        implements HeadlinesFragment.OnHeadlineSelectedListener {

    public void onArticleSelected(int position) {
           ArticleFragment articleFrag = (ArticleFragment)
                getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.article_fragment);

        if (articleFrag != null) {
            articleFrag.updateArticleView(position);
        }...

// ArticleFragment.java
public void updateArticleView(int position) {
    TextView article = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.article);
    article.setText(Ipsum.Articles[position]);
    mCurrentPosition = position;
}
```

Updated to include stack trace:

```
09-18 19:04:45.239    1291-1291/com.example.fragmentbasicsrebuild E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.fragmentbasicsrebuild.ArticleFragment.updateArticleView(ArticleFragment.java:74)
            at com.example.fragmentbasicsrebuild.MainActivity.onArticleSelected(MainActivity.java:66)
            at com.example.fragmentbasicsrebuild.HeadlinesFragment.onListItemClick(HeadlinesFragment.java:75)
            at android.app.ListFragment$2.onItemClick(ListFragment.java:160)
            at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
            at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2788)
            at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3463)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, firstly you shouldn't be using `getActivity().findViewById(R.id.article)` from within the fragment unless you're specifically trying to access something outside of your `Fragment`'s hierarchy (which would typically indicate you're doing something very, very wrong anyway).

What I would imagine is happening is that you're calling `getActivity().findViewById()` before your `Fragment`'s hierarchy has been added to the `Activity`. Instead of going through the `Activity`, simply use your `Fragment`'s `View`:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedState) {
    // "View view" is the view you returned in onCreateView(),
    // and also the same view that will now be returned by
    // calling getView().

    TextView articleText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.article);
}
```

As to why wrapping it in another layout causes it to work? No clue. Maybe you did something else different as well and forgot? Shouldn't make any difference, and you definitely don't *have* to wrap it in a layout if one isn't needed.

Comment: The `getActivity()` call is in a method invoked by a callback in the main activity, which isn't called until well after `onCreateView()`.  When I replace `getActivity()` with `GetView()` I still get the NPE.

Comment: Oddly, this is Google's own tutorial, not my code:  http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html

Comment: Can you post what you're doing in that callback? And how you get there? (How you're calling into the Activity; what the activity does to call back to the fragment, etc.)?

Comment: Updated to include relevant `MainActivity` and `ArticleFragment` code.

Comment: And you're saying that call to `getView().findViewById(R.id.article)` fails to locate the view?

Comment: Yes, as well as `getActivity()`.  Updated OP with stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Static Fragments tend to have some quirks. `getActivity().findViewById(R.id.article);` returns null probably from the same reason that `onCreateView` receives a null container (check it out).
You are probably better off with dynamically creating the Fragment: (code from http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager()
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragment = new ExampleFragment();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

See also [Android Fragment - onCreateView - container is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27306805/android-fragment-oncreateview-container-is-null) and [Android Fragment is given a null container in onCreateView()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16883831/android-fragment-is-given-a-null-container-in-oncreateview)