# Android Fragment - onCreateView - container is null

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a small problem with the onCreateView Method - the given container/parent is null and therefore i can't inflate my layout. Here is my code:

This is my "main" class

```
public class DrawerActivity extends ActionBarActivity
        implements NavigationFragment.NavigationListener {
    private static final int DRAWER_DELAY = 250;

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private NavigationFragment navigationFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // check if smartphone or tablet...
        if (isStaticMenuDrawer()) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawer_static);
        } else {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawer);
        }

    }

    protected void createMenuDrawer(int contentViewId) {
        ViewGroup content = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.content);
        content.addView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(contentViewId, null));

        navigationFragment = (NavigationFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.drawer_fragment);
        navigationFragment.initDrawer(R.id.drawer_fragment, R.id.drawer_layout, toolbar);

    }
}
```

This is my activity_drawer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" >


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <include layout="@layout/include_drawer"/>
    <include layout="@layout/include_toolbar"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is my OverviewActivity (my launcher/default activity)

```
public class OverviewActivity extends DrawerActivity {
    OverviewFragment overview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        createMenuDrawer(R.layout.activity_overview);
    }
}
```

my activity_overview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.xxxx.ui.overview.OverviewFragment"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_overview" />
```

and... my fragment

```
public class OverviewFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_overview, container, false);
    }
}
```

Can anybody explain me, why the container is null? Thanks... :)

Comment: As far I know, the View group is the view that will contains your layout. In many cases, it can be null and is not a big deal.   
You can change the parameter attach to root to **FALSE**     eg: inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_overview, container, false);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `<fragment>` needs to be contained in a view group when using the static approach. Just put a `RelativeLayout` as it's parent in the XML file.

Comment: Thanks.. can you explain me why i have to put it in a RelativeLayout?

Comment: Fragments need a parent view group when they are instantiated. So when you use them statically, they must be contained in a view group (layout). You could have used any of the available layouts, not just `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: But the DrawerLayout is a ViewGroup, I don't know why is the issue

Comment: I am adding a RelativeLayout as parent in xml but the container is still null